# apt-get update operation stuck at 0 shows 0% [working]

Tags: mysql, apache, server, debian, apt-get

I need to install mysql server, but the fact that I am not able to pass through the apt-get method. It shows `0% [working]` and doesn't have any end to this.

Help me out!

[See Terminal snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUWMA.png)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had SSHed into a server which wasn't connected to the Internet. Later on, when I enabled the Internet, update started.

Basically, I used `lynx any_web_site.com` then provided credentials for Internet Connectivity. That worked!

Answer (score 0):

update all **https** urls in `/etc/apt/sources.list` to **http**

```
cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak
apt-get update
apt-get install apt-transport-https
```

Optional:
change those urls in `/etc/apt/sources.list` back to https